# I have ceated a code that changes the password of win10 and wi11 in local PCs, but I do not know the problem in the code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

```
Imports System
Imports System.DirectoryServices

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Console.WriteLine("Local users:")
        For Each user As String In GetLocalUserList()
            Console.WriteLine("   " + user)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.Write("Enter Username: ")
        Dim s_name As String = Console.ReadLine()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(s_name) Then
            Console.Write("Enter new password: ")
            Dim s_password As String = Console.ReadLine()
            If ChangePassword(s_name, s_password) Then
                Console.WriteLine("Password updated!")
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR")
            End If
        End If
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...")
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Function GetLocalUserList() As List(Of String)
        Dim localDirectory As New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" & Environment.MachineName.ToString())
        Dim UserList As New List(Of String)
        For Each User As DirectoryEntry In localDirectory.Children
            If User.SchemaClassName = "User" Then
                UserList.Add(User.Name)
            End If
        Next
        Return UserList
    End Function


    Private Function ChangePassword(ByVal userName As String, ByVal password As String) As Boolean
        Try

            Dim localDirectory As New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" & Environment.MachineName.ToString())
            Dim user As DirectoryEntry = localDirectory.Children.Find(userName)
            If Not IsNothing(user) Then
                user.Invoke("SetPassword", password)
                Return True
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("User not found")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            If Not IsNothing(ex.InnerException) Then Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message)
        End Try
        Return False
    End Function

End Module
```

Comment: What is the problem? Did you get any error?

Comment: Just posting a wad of code and expecting us to work out what problem we're even supposed to be fixing is not acceptable. Please spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to ask a question properly. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.